# How to order documentation comments for a type coming from multiple impl blocks in different modules?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I have a struct and its implementation defined in `main.rs` and complementary implementations defined in other modules:

```rust
/// Bla bla.
pub struct Data {
    val: i32,
}

/// Primary functions.
impl Data {
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Data { Data { val } }
    pub fn get(&self) -> i32 { self.val }
}

/// FFI doc.
pub mod ffi {
    use super::Data;
    /// Additional functions for special cases.
    impl Data {
        pub fn adapt(&mut self) { self.val += 1; }
    }
}

/// Test doc.
pub mod test {
    use super::Data;
    /// Functions useful for tests.
    impl Data {
        pub fn report(&self) { println!("hello"); }
    }
}
```

When I generate the doc, the implementation blocks are shown in this order (and unfortunately without showing where the implementation blocks come from):

```
impl Data 
  Additional functions for restricted use.
  pub fn adapt(&mut self)

impl Data
  Functions useful for tests.
  pub fn report(&self)

impl Data
  Primary functions.
  pub fn new(val: i32) -> Data
  pub fn get(&self) -> i32
```

This does not seem alphabetical order of either relative or absolute module names (and it doesn't matter whether the crate name is `aaa` or `zzz`). What is the rule?

I would like the "primary" functions defined in the same module as the struct to be first, then the additional ones for specific cases (which are described in the documentation).

Is it possible?

Comment: Defining multiple implementation blocks for one type *in different modules* isn't common / idiomatic, except for the special case of tests. I'd encourage you to reorganize the code.

Comment: Otherwise, I believe that rustdoc uses the order of blocks and function you have defined, but modules are processed first.

Comment: @Shepmaster What would be the use of multiple implementation blocks if _not_ in different modules? Maybe only as a hack to organize documentation? Then if it needs organizing in a logical way, why not use modules (and different files)? I could reorganize the code to use plain functions with always a `&Data` first argument, but isn't it considered a hint that it could be made an implementation block? Also, I think it would imply to make some private members public.

Comment: Usually the different blocks are either implementing different traits (`impl Foo for A` / `impl Bar for A`) or have different constraints on generic types (`impl<T: Copy> Foo<T>` / `impl<T: Clone> Foo<T>`).

Comment: Ah, but those `impl` blocks are mandatory, whereas presenting plain functions as methods looks more as syntaxic sugar to me. Anyway, I have reorganized the code without `impl` blocks (using former self as mere first argument). Documentation becomes clearer because modules become real entries, and the code is not worse than before. So this was not an issue.

Comment: @Shepmaster, if the struct has +500 LOC of functions, and they can be logically separated, then multiple modules can make sense, no?

Comment: @JorgeLeitao not in the vast majority of Rust code I've read / written. From my experience, modules are only as suggested here when there's also conditional compilation that wants to apply to many things at once.